# Variants of double-slit experiment (Math meets Physics)

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

Double-slit experiment is a great experiment and is well-known for many mathematician and physicist [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment).
Actually, the math and calculation behind it is so simple and can explain many things which experimenter see it.
Recently, I designed three intellectual experiments that challenged me for saw it in mathematical manner. Also, it seems that their physical tests is so hard. These experiments are:

$1)$ If we bend the slits' plane and we create some curvature in this plane, what happens to the patterns?

$2)$ If the source of the light moves and go far and far from the plane of the slits (by the speed of near the speed of light), what happens to the experiment?

$3)$ If we move periodically ( (a)vertically, up and down, (b) Horizontally, back and front) the plane which has slits by speed "v" (v~c the speed of light), what happens to the experiment and the pattern?

For the questions #1 and #2, there are some hope for solving them by studying standard wave propagation field.

But for question #3, I do not have any idea. By consulting with professor Carlson (professor of quantum mechanic), I get the bellow answer:

**#3 will be much more difficult! For that, you may want to start from the Landau & Lifshitz text, Relativistic Quantum Theory. In fact, the theory is untested in the regime you propose!**

My question is about mathematical formulation of the question 3. Is there any similar  problem that has been solved? Actually,  Is there any random walk modeling for double-slit exprimen?
Any help and guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is better to ask on the physics stack exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because I agree with Alexandre Eremenko

Comment: What is the definition of "research level"? And why we have a mathematical physics tag here? I do not agree with you, but I respect to your comments! I hope you change your idea and reopen this question!

Comment: one reason why this question is not really appropriate here, is that it cannot be readily answered in the brief space of the answer box; if you have a specific mathematical point that comes up in this physics problem, then that would be on-topic in my opinion, but the question as phrased is basically to ask for someone here to carry out a research project in mathematical physics; a Q&A site such as this is not suitable for that.

Comment: Thanks dear Beenakker for your good explanation. If I ask for good references related to this question, is there any chances that the problem be open again?

Comment: I really don't think this is on-topic here, you might try the physics stackexchange, but in any case, here is a pointer to the literature: [Diffraction from moving gratings: negative energy solutions and relativistic effects](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960105017986)

Comment: Thanks dear Beenakker, I will move this question to physics stackexchange. Also, thanks for the paper. It seems helpful in some ways!